# Identifying Page Calling a Modal Page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a navigation bar menu button 'About' which should display the information about the page from where user has clicked on the menu bar button.

How can I pass the current :APP_PAGE_ID to this modal page, so that it shows the Page number from which page throughout the whole application the click has been made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question:

Populate Request as &APP_PAGE_ID. in Navigation Menu List Entry, like shown below:

[image]

Comment: That is one option. You could also create a page item on the modal page P800_CALLED_FROM and set that to APP_PAGE_ID in your link properties.